# Change width of man command ouput

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, manpage, terminal-emulator

I use Guake terminal emulator a lot. It's the best thing since sliced bred IMO.

But one thing has been bugging me, when I want to read man pages the default width of the output is the width of the terminal windows, which in my case is always full screen so it's a bit difficult to read.

Is there a way I can make the default width of the output of man command a, pleasant to read, 80 characters?

The man page for man has this part:

> ```
>    MANWIDTH
>           If  $MANWIDTH  is set, its value is used as the line length for which manual pages should be formatted.  If it is not set,
>           manual pages will be formatted with a line length appropriate to the current terminal (using an ioctl(2) if available, the
>           value  of  $COLUMNS,  or  falling  back  to 80 characters if neither is available).  Cat pages will only be saved when the
>           default formatting can be used, that is when the terminal line length is between 66 and 80 characters.
> ```

But I cant figure out where to change it.

I tried adding the line:

> MANWIDTH 80

to /etc/manpath.config and ~/.bashrc, but with no result.

Comment: Try with environment variable `COLUMNS`.

Comment: what happens if you run e.g. this oneliner: `MANWIDTH=40 man ls`

Comment: @nos it outputs with the width 40, I modified the ~/.bashrc to make it permanent

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's an environment variable.

Try:

```
MANWIDTH=80
export MANWIDTH
man bash
```

If you want that set permanently then you can add those first two lines to your shell session startup scripts or similar.

Comment: I added `export MANWIDTH=80` to the ~/.bashrc and it works. Why doesn't it work without `export`?

Comment: Without export you are setting it for the shell session itself only. No other processes see it. With `export` you are telling the shell to put it in the process environment so that child processes get the variable set in *their* environments when they start and they can then use the values to do things. `export var=value` and `var=value; export var` are identical except when `value` is a command when using `export var=$(command)` means you can't see the return code of the command you ran (and older shells don't support the `export var=value` format I believe).

Comment: a nice one: in your `~/.bashrc` file, add: `alias manw='MANWIDTH=$COLUMNS man'`   # will automagically have a man page fitting better to your own screen, even if you resize it (as long as you resize when on the prompt).  use then `manw` instead of `man`

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out in other answers, setting and exporting `MANWIDTH` properly is the way to go.

I would avoid hardcoding it, or else it will overflow / have ugly linebreaks when your terminal emulator window is more narrow than that value:

```
NAME
       grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines that match
 patterns

SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]
       grep [OPTION...] -e PATTERNS ... [FILE...]
       grep [OPTION...] -f PATTERN_FILE ... [FILE.
..]

DESCRIPTION
       grep  searches  for  PATTERNS  in  each  FI
LE.  PATTERNS is one or more
       patterns separated by newline characters, a
nd  grep  prints  each  line
       that  matches a pattern.  Typically PATTERN
S should be quoted when grep
       is used in a shell command.
```

Here's what I use, in a handy alias:

```sh
alias man='MANWIDTH=$((COLUMNS > 80 ? 80 : COLUMNS)) man'
```

This sets `MANWIDTH` to 80 if the terminal window is wider than that, and to `COLUMNS` (the current width of the terminal window) if it is more narrow.

Result in a wide window:

```
NAME
       grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines that match patterns

SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]
       grep [OPTION...] -e PATTERNS ... [FILE...]
       grep [OPTION...] -f PATTERN_FILE ... [FILE...]

DESCRIPTION
       grep  searches  for  PATTERNS  in  each  FILE.  PATTERNS is one or more
       patterns separated by newline characters, and  grep  prints  each  line
       that  matches a pattern.  Typically PATTERNS should be quoted when grep
       is used in a shell command.
```

Result in a narrow window:

```
NAME
       grep,  egrep, fgrep - print lines that
       match patterns

SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]
       grep  [OPTION...]  -e   PATTERNS   ...
       [FILE...]
       grep  [OPTION...]  -f PATTERN_FILE ...
       [FILE...]

DESCRIPTION
       grep searches  for  PATTERNS  in  each
       FILE.    PATTERNS   is   one  or  more
       patterns    separated    by    newline
       characters,  and grep prints each line
       that  matches  a  pattern.   Typically
       PATTERNS should be quoted when grep is
       used in a shell command.
```

Comment: I find that this works quite well: `export MANWIDTH="$((COLUMNS - 5))`. Setting the width to be the same as `COLUMNS` still had the effect of cutting off some of the text, and 80 was just too narrow

Comment: @smac89 I actually have it set to 120 for myself these days, which is quite comfortable to read, and avoids the super long lines I'd get from `COLUMNS - 5` if I have a very wide terminal window open. I think I used 80 here because otherwise the lines would overflow the code blocks.

Comment: I just looked in my config and it looks like I ended up going with a dynamic approach. I found the following in my `~/.zshrc` file: `function update_manpage_width() { export MANWIDTH="$((COLUMNS - 5))" }; precmd_functions+=(update_manpage_width)`. Basically everytime the prompt is redrawn, we compute a new width. I verified it works because when I split/zoom the terminal in `byobu`, the new width is updated

Answer (score 5):

You need to set this as an environment variable.

```
MANWIDTH=80 man man
```

works here, and provides the manpage for `man` in 80 column glory.

If you want this in `.bashrc` the correct line entry is

```
export MANWIDTH=80
```

Note lack of spaces around `=` sign. You may or may not need `export`.

Comment: The `export` was needed. I was close, didn't include the `=` sign -_- It works now. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know that you can set the env. variable like this: `MANWIDTH=80 man man` that is, in one line, thanks for that too.

Comment: The `VAR=value command` version is a way to set some number of environment variables for the command to be run only (and only for that single run).

Comment: You need the export so that the variable gets passed in the environment to child processes launched by the shell. I had a brain fade and couldn't remember whether that was automatically done for `.bashrc` files (it's not). The one liner version *only* sets the variable for the thing you are running (try `echo $MANWIDTH` after).

Answer (score -1):

> MANWIDTH=80 man bc

This is the simple way to control `man` page width on demand. It will override the value of `MANWIDTH` defined anywhere else.
To permanently change the `man` page width, set the environment variable `MANWIDTH` in the shell profile file. Then, there is no need to always have `MANWIDTH=80` before the `man` command.

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.